Not adding canva link in featured section
I tried to add my canva link in my featured section.
(Basically that was my portfolio presentation of 12 slides)
I tried it yesterday many times.
I thought it will easily be added just like my calendly link.
But it was showing "We're unable to retrieve your information. Use another link"
Although my link is publicly accessible.
